# VirtualAlloc address

Tags: c++, c, winapi, virtualalloc

I worte the code below

```
 void * ptr1 = VirtualAlloc((void*)0x70000000, 32*1024*1024, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
 void * ptr2 = VirtualAlloc((void*)0x80000000, 4*1024*1024, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

But VirtualAlloc fails and the value of ptr1,ptr2 are always NULL.
I want to use the adress 0x70000000,0x80000000.
Does anyone know how I can use these adress ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of the memory is not accessible for usermode applications. From the following [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909190.aspx):

> User applications cannot call **VirtualAlloc** with shared heap address
>   range (0x70000000 to 0x7fffffff) because this is read-only for user
>   applications and read/write for kernel mode.

Comment: Your link is Windows CE. I don't believe it's true for Windows in general. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I seem to recall above 0x70000000 being reserved for the kernel on Windows but couldn't find a reference for this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure some of the pages in the requested memory block are not already reserved (or committed)? VirtualAlloc cannot reserve a reserved page.

Why are 0x70000000 and 0x80000000 special? In the flat memory model, there is no reason why one address would be preferable to any other.